# Tail sigma algebra and 0-1 law

Tags: probability

Show that the event $\{ \sum_{n \geq 1} X_n > 1 \}$ is not a tail event.

I know the definition of a tail event and I know that if it were a tail event then $\mathbb{P}( \sum_{n \geq 1} X_n > 1 ) \in \{0,1 \}$, therefore it would be enough to find a counterexample, but I don't really know how to proceed to find one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence where $X_1$ is a standard normal and all the others are identically $0$.